# Parse json data form Youtube api

Tags: jquery, json, api, youtube

I have to parse the json data from this url http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=aNdMiIAlK0g&max-results=1&v=2&alt=jsonc using jquery. I have to extract the media:title and description of the video.
Anyone know how do that?

Comment: What language are you trying to parse it in?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're probably looking for jQuery.getJSON(): http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

```
var url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=aNdMiIAlK0g&max-results=1&v=2&alt=jsonc";
var title;
var description;
$.getJSON(url,
    function(response){
        title = response.data.items[0].title;
        description = response.data.items[0].description;
});
```

`getJSON` returns a response with property `data`, and `data` has a property of `items` which is an array. The array only has one item, so we're just using `items[0]`, and that item has a property `title` and a property `description` that we're going to save into our variables.

Hope this helps!

//edit: oops, yeah I thought response would be a better name for the variable, forgot to update the second line

Comment: I tryed this but got this response in firebug: data is not defined.

Comment: tahnk you, I found the error: description = response.data.items[0].description; You helped me a lot

Comment: @Mozart , do null check on data before start you accessing them

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
$.ajax({
   url: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=aNdMiIAlK0g&max-results=1&v=2&alt=jsonc,
   dataType: 'json',
   data: data,
   success: your_callback
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a JavaScript function to pull and display a YouTube channel listing (posted the code to StackOverflow). You can find it here:

[Getting all videos of a channel using youtube API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081301/getting-all-videos-of-a-channel-using-youtube-api/33767046#33767046)